# Transformation of Variables (Finding The Distribution)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, solution-verification, statistical-inference, transformation

Let $V \sim f(v) = Tv^2,$ such that $-2<v<1$ and $T$ is a constant. I want to know the distribution of $W=V^2$ and the value $T$. My attempt is that $V = \pm \sqrt{ W }.$ We know that
$$\int_{-2}^1  Kx^2 = 1  \quad \Rightarrow
3K  =1, \quad K = 1/3$$

Then $V\sim f(v) = \frac{1}{3}v^2, \ -2<v<1$ and $$F_V(v) = \int_{-2}^y \frac{1}{3} v^2 dy
 + \int_{y}^1 \frac{1}{3} v^2 dy = \frac{y^3+8}{9}+\frac{1-y^3}{9} = 1$$
Then,
\begin{align*}
F_V (W \le w) & = P(V \le \pm \sqrt{w})\\
& = P(-\sqrt{w} \le V \le \sqrt{w})\\
& = F_V(\sqrt{w}) - F_V(-\sqrt{w})\\
f_V(w) & = \frac12 f_V (w^{-1/2}) - \frac12 f_V (-w^{-1/2})\\
& = \frac12\left(\frac13(w^{-1}) \right) + \frac12\left(\frac13(w^{-1}) \right)\\
& \stackrel{?}{=}  \frac{1}{3}w
\end{align*}

Could that be wrong?

Comment: First of all I would solve $\int\limits_{-2}^{1} f(v) \ dv=1$ for $T$.

Comment: Have you read my comment or you just radomly make your edit?

Comment: I read it and updated my work.

Comment: Feel free to ask, if something is still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the constant is right. I continue later with your approach. First of all we need the cdf of $V$, since we work with inequalities. For this purpose we integrate the pdf from $-2$ (lower bound) to $v$:

$$\int_{-2}^v \frac13t^2 \ dt=\left[\frac19t^3\right]_{-2}^v=\frac{v^3}{9}+\frac{8}{9}$$

Thus the cdf is

$$F_V(v)=\begin{cases} 0, \  v\leq -2 \\ \frac{v^3}{9}+\frac{8}{9}, \  -2< v \leq 1 \\ 1, \  v>1  \end{cases}$$

Since the interval is not symmetric around 0 we make a case distinction:

*First case:* $v\in [-1,1) \Rightarrow w\in [0,1)$. Then we have $v=w^{1/2} $ for $v\in [0,1)$ and $v=-w^{1/2}$ for $v\in [-1,0)$

*Second case:* $v\in [-2,-1] \Rightarrow w\in [1,4]$

At the first case we can use your interval:

$$F_V(\sqrt{w}) - F_V(-\sqrt{w})=\left(\frac{w^{\frac32}}{9}+\frac{8}{9}\right)-\left(\frac{\left(-w^{1/2}\right)^3}{9}+\frac{8}{9}\right)$$

$$F_W(w)=\left(\frac{w^{\frac32}}{9}+\frac{8}{9}\right)-\left(\frac{-w^{3/2}}{9}+\frac{8}{9}\right)=\frac{w^{\frac32}}{9}+\frac{8}{9}+\frac{w^{\frac32}}{9}-\frac89=\frac{2}{9}w^{\frac32}$$

At the second case $V$ is negative. Thus we have

$P((-V)^2<w)=P(-V<w^{\frac12})=P(V>-w^{\frac12})=1-F\left(-w^{\frac12} \right)$

Inserting the value into the cdf results in

$$F_W(w)=1-\left(\frac{\left(-w^{\frac12}\right)^3}{9}+\frac{8}{9}\right)=1-\left(\frac{-w^{\frac32}}{9}+\frac{8}{9}\right)=\frac{w^{\frac32}}{9}+\frac19$$

Comment: I'm lost beginning from "...interval is not symmetric", what is rational for considering first and second cases? Wouldn't $F_W(w)$ has bounds?

Comment: @Ab2020 Your approach works only for sym. Intervals, since the values $-\sqrt w$ and $\sqrt w$ are symetric around $0$. Put in some numbers if it helps. Then for the interval $[-2,-1]$ we cannot bild such a symmetric interval and we have to regard a specific case. Sure the bounds are mentioned at the cases. Btw,  with these bounds you can make sanity checks, i.e. $1. F_W(0)=0, \ 2. F_W(1^-)=F_W(1), \ 3.  F_W(4)=1$

Comment: Probably, my problem is my inability to identify when to use the symmetric method and when not to use it. Can you give me some tricks/reference texts for me to be able to differentiate the two methods?

Comment: You have done it right for the symmetric part. Then we had to regard the part which was left.For all the steps probably some practice is necessary. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2131093/144421) is another exercise which you can make for training.

Comment: I've made some comments (a question) under the first answer: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2131093/transformation-of-random-variable-y-x2) but it seems that the user hasn't been back to the website for more than a year. Could you please read my comments and help me with my question over there? Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm still not able to grasp both 1st and 2nd cases. (1) Generally, how do you pick the intervals? For example, in your 1st case, you pick $v\in [-1,1)$ without saying how/why you pick it, then you came up with $w=[0,1),$ without showing how you had $w.$ (2) You then concluded that $v=w^{1/2}$ for $v\in[0,1)$ and again $v=w^{1/2}$ for $v\in [-1,0).$ (3) I'm struggling with that conclusion too. (4) Almost every textbook that I read do not provide details about how these intervals are obtained. They just assumed the reader knows, which is always a wrong assumption.

Comment: @Ab2020 I' ve divided the allover interval in a symmetric Intervall and  the remaining interval. Quote: "*Since the interval is not symmetric around 0 we make a case distinction*"  I thought rhis was clear.

Comment: I know that $v=[-2,-1,0,1]$ if the split is at 0, do you mean $v_1=[-1,1]$ or $v_1=[-1,1)$? and how was $w=[0,1)?$

Comment: @Ab2020 I was not finished with my comment. I hope it clarifies some questions. Ad 2) The split is at $v=0$. For $v\in [0,1)$ we can insert the values  $0=0^{1/2} $ and $1=1^{1/2} $ This is true. For the negative part,  $v\in [-1,0)$,we must add a negative sign. We cannot calculate a root of a negative value:  $v=-w^{1/2}$. Inserting the values of -1 and 0 gives $-1=-1^{1/2}$ and $0=-0^{1/2}$ This is true as well // The distinction between ) and ] is not so imposant. The crucial point is that the interval has no gaps.

Comment: If I understand what you mean about the spilt been at 0 is that you pick the number to the right of 0 to form the interval: $[0, 1]$ and also pick the number to the left of 0 to form: $[-1,0]$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142633/discussion-between-ab2020-and-callculus42).

Comment: Yes. If you want to be very precise with the brackets then the second interval is $[-1,0)$. So the intervals do not overlap.